# Threading For Computing User's Data in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm new to C++ (and threading in general), so I'm hoping you guys can help.

I have several users and I'm given their data which is in the form of corresponding CSVs. For each user, I have to do many computations, save their individual output, and add their individual output to a large array and save that.

Anyway, my code looks a little something like this:

```
for(unsigned int i=0; i<numUsers; i++){
    LoadPerson(&pName, &pNum); //Loads a User's Data and kicks of compuation
}
```

I have a couple of questions:

1) Can I use threading for this? Can I have several of these computations going at once and when it's done, append to the large array mentioned above.

2) I think if I do that, I'll have to lock the large array because multiple threads can't append to the same array at the same time. Is that assumption correct/how would I go about that?

3) Is there a limit to the number of threads I can have at once? If each user gets their own thread, and let's say I have 50 users, is that too much? Or should I do something where I only kick of 10 users at once, then when one finishes another one starts? So, for example, I would only kick off user 11 when user 1 finishes. Again, how can I implement that with threading?

4) Any other suggestions would be great too. This is for a machine learning project and I have to comb through a lot of data for pre-processing before I can even start doing my modeling. It's pretty slow. I have a feeling most of this inefficiency is from reading these very large CSVs (threading might help). But if you have any other tips, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I don't care if you down vote the question, but please tell me why. I'm just here to learn

Comment: Your question is too broad. You are asking several questions at once, some of which can be answered with entire books, some of which are purely opinion-based, and some that have already been answered on Stackoverflow and are thus duplicates. Please try to narrow down your question to a specific issue, and if you have multiple questions, post them separately. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Reminder:  There is an overhead (space and execution) to maintain threads.  Threads may not be executed on separate cores; they could share the same processor.

Comment: It depends *a lot* on your system. Some only have a single slow CPU and little memory, or you might have an IBM z14 mainframe with 170 CPUs at 5+ Ghz. There 50 users wouldn't even be noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the context wasn't very precise so the answer is kind of generic

> Can I use threading for this? Can I have several of these computations
>   going at once and when it's done, append to the large array mentioned
>   above.

if there is little to no data that would be shared between threads you can do this computation in multi-thread efficiently

> I think if I do that, I'll have to lock the large array because
>   multiple threads can't append to the same array at the same time. Is
>   that assumption correct/how would I go about that?

you are right you need a synchronization mechanism like locks

> Is there a limit to the number of threads I can have at once? If each
>   user gets their own thread, and let's say I have 50 users, is that too
>   much? Or should I do something where I only kick of 10 users at once,
>   then when one finishes another one starts? So, for example, I would
>   only kick off user 11 when user 1 finishes. Again, how can I implement
>   that with threading?

the system imposes limit on the maximum amont of threads but it is often much higher than what you want to have, if you want good performances you should have as much threads as your cpu has cores(provided threads have similar loads). 50 threads is probably to much

Answer (score 0):

Think of the processing as data flowing through a pipeline.
The pipeline has different sections:  read, compute, output.

```
+-----------+--------------+-------------+  
| Read data | Compute data | Output Data |  
+-----------+--------------+-------------+
```

Each section can be a thread.
The Read section reads some data then passes it to the Compute section.
The Compute section processes the data, then passes to the Output section.

By having each section as threads, you can have buffers so that the execution can be processed "in parallel".

This is one of many scenarios that threading can be applied.